# Numerical computation of the Spherical harmonics expansion

Tags: python, math

I'm trying to understand the Spherical harmonics expansion in order to solve a more complex problem but the result I'm expecting from a very simple calculation is not correct. I have no clue why this is happening.

---

**A bit of theory:** It is well known that a function on the surface of a sphere ([image: \mathbb{R}^{3}]) can be defined as an infinite sum of some constant coefficients [image] and the spherical harmonics [image] :

[image]

The spherical harmonics are defined as :

[image]

where [image] are the associated Legendre polynomials.

An finally, the constant coefficients [image] can be calculated (similarly to the Fourier transform) as follow:

[image]

---

**The problem:** Let's assume we have a sphere centered in [image] where the function on the surface is equal to [image] for all points  [image]. We want to calculate the constant coefficients and then calculate back the surface function by approximation.  Since [image] the calculation of the constant coefficients reduces to :

[image]

which numerically (in Python) can be approximated using:

```
def Ylm(l,m,theta,phi):
    return scipy.special.sph_harm(m,l,theta,phi)

def flm(l,m):
    phi, theta = np.mgrid[0:pi:101j, 0:2*pi:101j]
    return Ylm(l,m,theta,phi).sum()
```

Then, by computing a band limited sum over [image] I'm expecting to see [image]  when [image] for any given point [image].

[image]

```
L = 20
f = 0
theta0, phi0 = 0.0, 0.0
for l in xrange(0,L+1):
    for m in xrange(-l,l+1):
        f += flm(l,m)*Ylm(l,m,theta0,phi0)
print f
```

but for [image] it gives me [image] and not [image]. For [image] it gives me [image]

I know it seems more a Mathematics problem but the formulas should be correct. The problem seems being on my computation. It could be a really stupid mistake but I cannot spot it. Any suggestion?

Thanks

Comment: I agree with your theory section, but the problem you state miraculously uses a sum instead of an integral for f^l_m. Are you sure that you don't want to multiply each element of the sum with the size of the element? Otherwise the integral would depend on the number of elements you use for discretization.

Comment: Maybe I'm wrong but, to my understanding, an integral in a continuous space reduces to a sum in a discrete space (as for the Discrete Fourier transform). Effectively a scaling factor could be the solution but I don't see how to retrieve this value. The number of sums I do for L=20 is 441. The value should be around 1/12860 according to the results I got.

Comment: You're right, you can use a sum instead of an integral, and maybe I didn't understand what you were doing. My point is that you can't just drop the d Omega without replacing it with some form of delta Omega_ij when you transform the integral to a sum. In your case, each element of your sum is a kuboid with height Y^l_m(...) and a base area of( pi/100)*(pi/2/100), so dOmega is around 1/2000, which is off by a factor of 2 pi. I guess using sin(theta) for integration with spherical coordinates will take care of that, as dmuir writes.

Comment: That integral appears to be a path integral to me.  Is that how you coded it?  I would expect to see a discretization of that path and something like Gaussian quadrature to evaluate each piece.

Comment: Yes, as mars and dmuir pointed out, the spherical integral cannot be translated in a simple sum. The problem I'm trying to solve comes form this article http://lmb.informatik.uni-freiburg.de/papers/download/fe_bu_icpr08.pdf and especially equation 8. Either the article is wrong or my understanding of it is wrong. And yes, as pointed out in this thread http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1337806/integrating-over-particular-grids-to-obtain-spherical-harmonic-coefficients the integral can be evaluated numerically using gaussian Quadrature but I'm not sure how to find the coeffs. omegaN

Answer (score 1):

The spherical harmonics are orthonormal with the inner product

```
<f|g> = Integral( f(theta,phi)*g(theta,phi)*sin(theta)*dphi*dtheta)
```

So you should calulate the coefficients by

```
  clm = Integral( Ylm( theta, phi) * sin(theta)*dphi*dtheta)
```

Comment: So I should be able to calculate the coefficient f using a sum like: `flm = Sum( Ylm( theta, phi) * sin(theta) )` which translate into a Python code like: 
    `def flm(l,m):
       phi, theta = np.mgrid[0:np.pi:101j, 0:2*np.pi:101j]
       return np.multiply(Ylm(l,m,theta, phi),np.sin(theta)).sum()
`
?

Comment: Sorry, I don't know python but I think you need to normalise that. If you 'integrate' the constant 1 you should get 4*pi (the area of the sphere), so the normalisation constant is 4*pi/whatever-you-get